# thermodynamics problem

Tags: thermodynamics

The boiling point of a substance $X$ at 1 atm pressure is $500 k$ . The enthalpy of vapourisation at the boiling point of $X$ (l) is 80 kj/mol .The molar specific heat of $X(l)$ = $5 × 10^{-3}$ kj/mol and $C_p$ of X(g) = $5 ×10^{-4}$ kj/mol 
What is the molar latent heat of vapourisation of $X(l)$ at $800 K$ and at $1 atm$ ?

Options : 
A: lesser than $80 kJ$ $\\$
B: greater than $80 kJ$ $\\$
C : equal to $80kJ$ $\\$
D: Since 800K is the higher temperature than the boiling point of $X(l)$ ; therefore , enthalpy of vapourisation is not applicable

Comment: I'm wondering how this HW question got two upvotes in 3 min after publication.

Comment: Should be able to solve by Kirchhoff's Law? Or simply logically, Cp of gas lower, as T increases enthalpy of gas increases less than enthalpy of liquid increases, so the reaction becomes less endothermic.

Comment: If its equilibrium vapor pressure at 500 K is 1 atm, how can it also be 1 atm at 800 K?